# Marshelling exception in CORBA

Tags: c++, corba

When i tried to register my POA in corba, i am getting Marshelling exception. I registered all registry already with my object. 
I m using ACE/TAO 2.0a
Any help appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Architecture has been changed in corba since 1.3a now you have to try registering all MarshellingProxyies that supply. Please have a look at new registryfactory in CORBA 2.2a,

Comment: I think that is probably error, should i add all object to this new registry?

Comment: Yes sumit I would strongly say that